# how to submit form after calling e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateInputs();


});
```

how to submit the form in given js

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from your question, but I will make this assumption:

- I will assume that the function `validateInputs` returns `true` if all the inputs are considered valid, and returns `false` if there is one or more error found in the form inputs.

---

You can call `form.submit()` to programmatically submit the form.

In the context of your existing code, applying the assumption I've listed above:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (validateInputs()) {
        // All inputs are valid, submit the form.
        form.submit();
    } else {
        // Run some code here that points out the problems in the form
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

find your submit button and add click event

```
function checkForm()
{
   if(validateInputs())
   {
      form.submit();
   }
}
button.addEventListener("click",checkForm);
```